# Is possible export just 1 object and not whole page? (Javascript, export/import)

Tags: javascript, oop, import, module, export

I am trying export and import my objects in js files, but my console throws errors like

> 1. Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SetStorage' before
>    initialization.

and script tag in my HTML:

Thank you.

Kind regards Miriam.

I think problem is with loading page, but I am not sure.

[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvM9W.png)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzIpj.png)

[error on line 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3RaB.png)

Comment: which file and line number is throwing that error? I don't see how it can come from the code you've shared, and I think it's more likely to be the `databaseInsurance` module that is at fault. But without seeing the code, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Hi, I just added 3 pictures in my question. Thank you.